# getSimpleName from a BaseActivity after finish()

Tags: android

in my App I created a BaseActivity, from which I extend all my Activities.

Inside the BaseActivity I recognize the activity that is running through the following statement: `this.getClass().getSimpleName() (ex: ActivityA)`

Until I open new Activity (`ActivityB`, `ActivityC`, etc ...) everything works correctly.

The problem occurs when I use the back button of the phone (I get back from `activityC` to `ActivityB`). In this case the `ActivityB` is properly resumed from the Stack, but in `BaseTable` (of `ActivityB`) the value of `this.getClass().getSimpleName()` remains `ActivityC`.

How can I avoid this problem? You know you help me?

Comment: Can you give some code, to show how and where do you call this.getClass().getSimpleName()?

Comment: In onResume Method of my BaseActivity...

<code>
public class BaseActivity extends Activity implements ConnectorDelegate {
 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        MyApplication.getConnectionManager().setDelegate(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();


MyApplication.getConnectionManager().startListening(this);

currentActivityName=this.getClass().getSimpleName();
 }

......
</code>

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is create a `protected final String` in your BaseActivity as follows...

```
public class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {

    protected final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    // Any other code here

}
```

Any `Activity` which extends `MyBaseActivity` will inherit the `TAG` field and it will be instantiated with the correct name at the time it's created.

I put a `TAG` field in all of my Android base classes so I can use it with `Log` to identify different objects when they log to logcat.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. 
The problem is the same as before. When i Go Back the value of TAG remains the old one.

Comment: @user2381742 : I can assure you it does work although I use `getClass().getName()` which gives a fully qualified name rather than the simple class name. You mention `BaseTable` - what is that?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong to write. I Wanted to write BaseActivity

Comment: @user2381742 How do you determine that it does not work? Do you use debugger or you print that string? Do you check the value at the correct time? Maybe you check inside onPause() of ActivityC?